# How can Mongo query specify that two conditions in an array are satisfied at the same time?

Tags: mongodb

For example, the doc is

```
{'id':'1',
  'tag':[{'tag_a':'A',
          'score':'10'},
         {'tag_b':'B',
           'score':'0'}
        ]
}
```

I want get the doc that satisfied tag_b get 10 points in my collection. Obviously, I should not get this doc. However, when I use the query below

```
{$and:[{'tag.tag_b':'B','tag.score':'10'}]}
```

This doc will appear in the results.
How can I avoid this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Use the `$elemMatch` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found that
 "find({'tag':{'tag_b':'B', 'score':'10'}})"  
can work too.

Comment: You mean `{ 'tag': {'tag_b': 'B', 'score': '0' } }`?

Comment: When I want to search tag_b get 10 points, I can use { 'tag': {'tag_b': 'B', 'score': '10' } }, and the example doc I gave above will not appear in the result. That is the situation I want. Of course, your answer work  and  better in some situation. Thanks again!